# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED via localhost access( React -> Django )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django

I made dev environment underbelow.
Container is Docker container.

```
                       +-----------------------------------------------------+
                       |       ◎http://192.168.1.1:8040/                    |
                       |                                                     |
                 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                 |     |                                                     |  [ubuntu]     |
                 |     |                                                     | (192.168.1.1) |
                 |     |  +-----------------------------------------------+  |               |
                 |     |  |    ✖ http://172.17.0.1:8040/                 |  |               |
                 |     |  |                                               |  |               |
                 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
                 ||    |  |                                               |  |  [container]| |
                 ||    |  |                                               |  | (172.17.0.1)| |
                 || +--+--+--+                                            |  |             | |
                 || | React  |                                            |  |             | |
           +--------> nodejs +-----------------------------------------+  |  |             | |
           |     || |        | ✖ http://localhost:8040/               |  |  |             | |
           |     || +--------+ ✖ http://127.0.0.1:8040/               |  |  |             | |
           |     ||                                                    v  v  v             | |
           |     || +--------+                                        ++--+--+---+         | |
           |     || |        |                                        |          |         | |
+---------+ | +------> nodejs +--------------------------------------->+  Django  |         | |
|         | | |   || |        | ◎ http://localhost:8040/              |          |         | |
|         +-+ |   || +--------+ ◎ http://127.0.0.1:8040/              ++--+------+         | |
|         |   |   ||                                                    ^  ^                | |
|         +---+   || +--------+                                         |  |                | |
| Browser |       || |        |                                         |  |                | |
| (winPC) +----------> Flask  +-----------------------------------------+  |                | |
|         |       || |        | ◎ http://localhost:8040/                  |                | |
|         +---+   || +--------+ ◎ http://127.0.0.1:8040/                  |                | |
+---------+   |   ||                                                       |                | |
             |   || +--------+                                            |                | |
             |   || |        |                                            |                | |
             +------>cmd-line+--------------------------------------------+                | |
                 || |        | ◎ curl –X GET http://127.0.0.1:8040/                       | |
                 || +--------+ ◎ curl –X GET http://127.0.0.1:8040/                       | |
                 ||                                                                        | |
                 |-------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
                 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From "React + nodejs" srv to "Django" srv,
I couldn't access using 'http://localhost:8040/' or 'http://127.0.0.1:8040/'( both err = ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED )
I could acces only using 'http://10.128.130.47:8040/'

From "Flask" srv or "nodejs" srv to "Django" srv,
I couldn't access using 'http://localhost:8040/' and 'http://127.0.0.1:8040/'

Are there any limitation or setting problem in DJango access via localhost(or 127.0.0.1 ) in React(nodejs)?

Dnago srv setting.[settings.py]

```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'corsheaders',
       ....
   ]
   
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       ....
   ]
   CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL  = True
```

React src.

```
class App extends Component {
   state ={
      todos: []
   };

  componentDidMount(){
     this.getTodos();
  }
  
   axios
       .get('http://localhost:8040/')
       .then( res =>{
               this.setState({ todos: res.data });
       }
      .catch( err =>{
      
      
   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               {this.state.todos.map(item => (
                   <div key={item.id}>
                       <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                       <p>{item.body}</p>
                   </div>
               ))}
            </div>
      )
  }
}
```